# Unable to read RGB data from .xlsx cell

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have a simple .xlsx file which has cells of different colors. I need to get the colors and check if they are RED, YELLOW or GREEN.

The excel file looks like this:

[image]

For that I tried to write the code as following:

```
// get Cell color for specificed cells
        CellStyle cellStyle = currentCell.getCellStyle();
        XSSFCellStyle xssfCellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) cellStyle;
        XSSFColor color = xssfCellStyle.getFillBackgroundXSSFColor();

        // check for null - when there is no cell background color, it returns null
        if (null != color) {
            String rgb =  color.getCTColor().getDomNode().getAttributes().getNamedItem("rgb").getNodeValue();
        }
```

This code throws NullPointerException, because, here `color.getCTColor().getDomNode().getAttributes().getNamedItem("rgb") == null`.

Then I worked on another approach which is following:

```
// get Cell color for specificed cells
        CellStyle cellStyle = currentCell.getCellStyle();
        XSSFCellStyle xssfCellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) cellStyle;
        XSSFColor color = xssfCellStyle.getFillBackgroundXSSFColor();
        if (color != null) {
            cellObject.setBackgroundColor(color.getARGBHex());
            System.out.println("row: " + rowIndex + "col: " + colIndex + "color : " + color.getARGBHex());
        }
```

But, in this approach the the value for `color.getARGBHex()` in each cell as `null`.

Edit: I tried another simpler approach which is the following:

```
//get cell colors
        short style = currentCell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor();
        System.out.println("row:"+rowIndex+",col:"+colIndex+" color: "+style);
```

This code returns the value for every cell: `64`

Edit: As per Axel's suggestion, I tried this code:

```
short xssfColor = currentCell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor();
```

But, this code returns 64 for white cells and 0 for non-white cells.

Can anyone please help in this regard?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are fiddling with the wrong. Excels cell fills are pattern fills. There fill **background** color is the color behind the pattern and fill **foreground** color ist the color of the pattern. Normally a cell ist filled using SOLID_FOREGROUND pattern. So the color of the pattern is needed and not the color behind the pattern. Try `getFillForeground...Color...` instead of `getFillBackground...Color...`.

Comment: Hello, Axel, thank you so much for the comments. This resolves the issue partially. Let me explain. I tries this code: short xssfColor = currentCell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor(); This identifies white and non-white cells. For white cells it return 64, but for non-white cells it returns 0. Unfortunately, I need to identify RED, GREEN and YELLOW cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Axel for the hint. Using his hint, I was able to solve this problem.

I used this code for solving this problem.

```
// get cell colors
        XSSFColor xssfColor = (XSSFColor) currentCell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
        if (xssfColor != null)
            System.out.println("row:" + rowIndex + ",col:" + colIndex + " color: " + xssfColor.getARGBHex());
```

This clearly differentiates between all the colors. getARGBHex() returns RGB components along with the Alpha value. But, it is easy string operation to extract the RGB from the data

For example:

`Red : FFFF0000` (returned by `getARGBMex()` method, so RGB value is: FF0000).

Thanks again Axel for your help.